# Is there a way in Illustrator to "snap" open paths to a curve or detect when they are not?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, snapping, bezier-curve

We are working on projects that are basically all open paths. However, we run into the following situation a lot:

[image]

If we change the shape of one curve, all other paths that had "intersected" are now off. Is there someway to keep an anchor point "snapped" to a curve? (Similar to connectors in OmniGraffle, etc.)

Or is there an easy way to detect where these have occurred in the document? "Join" doesn't work because they are not two anchor points.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prevent, detect, connect, or align -- Nope**

**Trim -- Yes.**

- Extend the paths beyond the curve.
- Select the paths and the curve
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key
- Drag across the extended paths.

[image]

There's no way to *prevent* or *detect* misalignment on a curve that I'm aware of. And there's absolutely no way to "connect" a path to the middle of another path.

Comment: Thanks, @Scott. That is a very useful tool. However, I think we will still run into the same problem. In order to extend the paths beyond the curve, when you drag the anchor points isn't there still the risk of changing these curve shapes and throwing off intersections elsewhere? (That is, sometimes the points don't already extend past the curve like the one on the left of my example image.)

Comment: Yes. I don't know of any shortcut to quality work. You just have to be mindful of what you are doing.

Comment: Your method works great for paths that already extend further than they should. For paths that are too short, I started adding an additional anchor point on the curve I was going to extend. That way when I modify the path, it doesn't alter the shape of that path elsewhere.

Comment: @robertwbradford There exists tools that can automatically extend curves for ilustrator as plugins